# How to record video of concurrent test executions in Robotframework+Selenium Headless

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework, video-capture

I have automated tests using Robotframework+Selenium that are running in parallel, in the same machine.

Is it possible to record a video individually foreach execution and not for the machine desktop?

I do know that in Ruby, there is something like the xvfb that can be configured at headless browser to record the execution.

I only need the same for Python/Robotframework (Windows).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you consider using cloud services to deliver this? e.g. browserstack

Comment: What you ask is an advice for which set of tools will work for your particular requirements and setup. That is a bold ask, and certainly not within the scope of what [so] is for. When you've made your tool set choice and have technical issues that need help resolving, feel free to ask them here.